# How to extend time for program to finish after USR2 signal

Tags: lsf

I have got a program that will run for a very long time on my universities LSF cluster. I don't know if it will finish before it exceeds its job's time limit. If a job exceeds the time limit, the LSF system will send increasingly unfriendly termination signals to the program before it is finally killed. I programmed the code to catch the USR2 signal and save its data, however this will need a few minutes. In my university's guide to using the LSF system, it states that the option

```
-ta USR2 -wt [hh:]mm
```

extends the time limit the program has to react to USR2.

I already tried to following options:

```
-ta USR2 -wt '00:20'
```

```
-ta USR2 -wt 00:20
```

```
-ta USR2 -wt 20
```

```
-ta USR2 -wt '20'
```

and all of the above where

```
USR2
```

is replaced by

```
'USR2'
```

I hoped that the job would be submitted, but there is an error occuring:

```
a: Bad time specification. Job not submitted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want

```
-wa USR2 -wt 20
```

`-ta` isn't a bsub option.  So bsub thinks you're asking for a termination deadline `-t` with a time spec of `a`. Hence the error message

```
a: Bad time specification. Job not submitted.
```